# how find out if force layout done placing the nodes?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have graph based on force layout. I would like to put a 'loading' overlay until the graph is done placing the nodes. What event/property can I use to find out that graph is done?

I checked the API, could not find anything..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the layout converges, `force.alpha()` will be set to 0. Set a timer to poll for that (not too often!) and you'll know when you're done.

This example should retry every `interval` milliseconds until the layout stops. The variable `timer` keeps the current timer, which you can reset if you don't want to wait for the layout to complete any more.

```
var timer = null;
function onCompletion(force, callback, interval) {
    interval = interval || 300;

    function retryIfRunning() {
        if (force.alpha() != 0)
            timer = setTimeout(checkAndRetry, interval);
        else {
            timer = null;
            callback();
        }
    }

    retryIfRunning();
}
```

Answer (score 19):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#on), the `end` event is dispatched when the layout is done, i.e. when `force.alpha === 0`.

So you can find out when it is done with:

```
force
  .nodes(yourNodes)
  .links(yourLinks)
  .on('tick', function() {
    // layout is in progress
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // layout is done
    callback();
  });
```

Comment: This is way shorter then the accepted solution! @TO maybe switch accetion?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as a built in feature as it depends on what you consider as being done with   placing nodes. The way it is done is by calling the `tick` function `n` times, with `n`depending on the size of the graph you have and the precision you want.

> #force.tick(): Runs the force layout simulation one step.

I encourage you to read the `force.tick()` documentation if you want to know more: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-tick